# In Google Calendar, is it possible to edit the title of an event without having to go to the event's page?

Tags: google-calendar

Before the refresh, one could click on an event in the calendar view and it would show a popup where the event title was editable. In the redesign, the event popup does not allow the editing of the event's title any longer. The only way I've found to do it is by clicking on "edit event" on the popup, which brings me to the event's page.

Is there a way to edit it on the calendar view? If not, is there a way to revert back to the old Google Calendar (my settings no longer show an option for that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Google is locked into this new calendar view. Some users can still revert to the classic view -- but only until Feb 28th -- while others lost that ability on Feb 5th.

You can read more about it here:

https://9to5google.com/2018/01/04/google-calendar-material-design-january/

In the new calendar view, there doesn't seem to be a way to rename an event without bringing up the edit screen. Right-clicking on an event only gives you the option to delete that event or change its background color.